# mod_rewrite condition and rule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've searched for this and Im probably just sitting to close but I cant seem to get this rewrite to work. I have a file on a directory that I want to redirect to a vhost domain on the same server. Below is my condition, rule, and vhost

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/main$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R,l]

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias domain.com
DocumentRoot /data/live/main
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Seems to me you only need `RewriteRule ^main/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R,L]`

Comment: That setups an infinite redirect if I remove the conditional and if I keep it, nothing happens and the redirect doesnt take effect.

Comment: According to your virtual host your 2 domains are already being redirected to /main, so I don't really understand what you are trying to do here, however you cannot use HTTP_HOST for folders.

Comment: Currently one can go to www.olddomain.com/main/ and get the content and also www.newdomain.com and get the same content. The goal would be to have one outward facing entity. 

So my setup is as follows:

`www.olddomain.com/main/`
`www.newdomain.com/ - vhost`

but all the content lives on the olddomain and the newdomain is just a vhost on the same box as the olddomain.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: so you want to redirect olddomain to the new domain ? or just the main folder of the olddomain to the newdomain ?

Comment: olddomain subfolder to the newdomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect the `olddomain` folder `main` to the `newdomain` then you can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^main/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you want to redirect all the content of the `olddomain` to the `newdomain` then you can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And if you want to remove the `www` from your `newdomain`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or you can do it directly on the `virtualhost` like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName newdomain.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.newdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /data/live/main
</VirtualHost>
```